# Python Scipy Optimization curve_fit

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have two numpy arrays x and y and would like to fit a curve to the data. The fitting function is an exponential with a and t as fitting parameters, and another numpy array ex.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.optimize as op

k=1.38e-23
h=6.63e-34
c=3e8

def func(ex,a,t):
    return a*np.exp(-h*c/(ex*1e-9*kb*t))

t0=300 #initial guess
print op.curve_fit(func,x,y,t0)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. For us to be able to help you, please specify what your question is and how your problem manifests itself.

Comment: Please check documentation of [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). Your function definition is incorrect. Have a look at the first example, which is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @user2993263 did you check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial guess should contain two values like `t0=(300, 1.)` since you have two fitting parameters (`a` and `t`).

You need to define the points you want to fit, i.e. defining `x` and `y` before calling `curve_fit()`.